# F# run blocking call on another thread, use in async workflow

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I have a blocking call `blockingFoo()` that I would like to use in an `async` context. I would like to run it on another thread, so as to not block the `async`.

Here is my solution:

```
let asyncFoo = 
  async {
    blockingFoo() |> ignore
  }
  |> Async.StartAsTask
  |> Async.AwaitTask
```

- Is this the correct way to do this?
- Will this work as expected?

Answer (score 7):

I think you're a bit lost. `Async.StartAsTask` followed by `Async.AwaitTask` effectively cancel each other, with the side-effect that the `Task` created in the process actually triggers evaluation of the async block containing `blockingFoo` on the thread pool. So it works, but in a way that betrays expectations.

If you want to trigger evaluation of `asyncFoo` from within another async block, a more natural way to do it would be to use `Async.Start` if you don't want to await its completion, or `Async.StartChild` if you do.

```
let asyncFoo = 
    async {
        blockingFoo() |> ignore
    }

async {
    // "fire and forget"
    asyncFoo |> Async.Start

    // trigger the computation
    let! comp = Async.StartChild asyncFoo

    // do other work here while comp is executing

    // await the results of comp
    do! comp
}
```

Comment: How should I rewrite `asyncFoo` such that I don't have to remember to do `Async.StartChild` on each call?

Comment: Do what makes sense in the context of your codebase. As a rule of thumb I would prefer seeing the `Async.StartChild` on each call, because it makes it easier to tell what is happening. But if calling asyncFoo will be a common operation and the fact it kicks off a computation in the background will be well understood by the users, then you might want to "hide" it in order to have cleaner code.